# Parser Error Pandas while reading excel to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data

def open_doc(datastream): #read with pandas CHECK
df = pd.read_csv(datastream, sep=";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")  
return df
```

This function used to work before for different Excel-datasets.

Suddenly while trying to reuse it in a new script I receive this error. 
Tried:

```
 escapechar
```

and

```
different delimiter
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED! 
Had to restart anaconda.. feeling kind of dumb now :D